# Disable Sleep in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: sleep, ubuntu-11.10

I recently migrated from Fedora to Ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop. I'm really happy with the change so far, except that I often have the need to run a series of hour-long jobs overnight, and as best I can tell, Ubuntu goes to sleep after about an hour and a half nomatter what I do.

I can only tell because when I hit a key to wake the screen up in the morning it takes a few seconds (normally comes up instantly), and when I check its progress a series of tasks that should've taken 4 hours max is less than halfway done. I know it's not the job just taking longer than it should - I'm basically running the same thing over and over, and I inserted date commands between each run and I can see the jobs running exactly as long as I expect, up until it hits the point where it just stops, usually after the first or second run.

I would expect this to be fairly trivial to solve but it's really important for what I'm doing that I get this figured out. I have the power settings on "Don't Suspend" regardless of whether it's charging or not (and I obviously leave it charging when I do this), I leave the lid up, and I tried installing Jupiter and setting it Maximum Performance. No dice. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So I found a solution, I installed Caffeine and set it to force the computer to stay awake when bash is on, which seems to have solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

[This site](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/07/from-windows-to-ubuntu-turn-off-sleep-mode/) lists what you have to do.

```
Power >> System Settings >> Hardware >> Power Management
```

Comment: I have already done that, I changed that setting as soon as I installed it but it doesn't seem to be helping. That's largely why I'm confused.

Comment: Edited because I just got disciplined for link rot.

Comment: @harper89 lol no problem

Comment: @AddisonMayberry I did the same and had no issues.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug other people are reporting. Here is a [fix](http://thecodecentral.com/2011/01/18/fix-ubuntu-10-10-suspendhibernate-not-working-bug) that may work. There is also another link under that article that may be more associated with your problem.

The fix is a little lengthy so I won't post the whole thing.

Comment: I tried this but no success, I figured it out using a different method. Thanks though.